# How to convert a Sitecore package into a WDP package?

Tags: azure, paas, packages, package-designer

How can I convert a given **Sitecore Package** previously created using the *Package Designer* into a **WDP package**, so that I can create a script to deploy it on my Azure instances?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Prerequisites

- [Download](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit.aspx) the AzureToolkit from Sitecore.
- [Powershell](http://powershelltutorial.net/Home/Powershell-Download) 4.x or newer ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion to check your current version)
- [Download](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) and install MSDeploy.
- [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) (The express version is enough)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFX)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55713) for SQL server 2012 or later.

## Steps

1 - Import the methods you will need from AzureToolkit to the current PowerShell session.

```
Import-Module "AzureToolkitFolderPath\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll" -Verbose
```

2 - Convert the input package using the `ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage` method.

```
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path "yourPackagePath.zip" -Destination "wdpOutputDirectoryPath" -force -verbose
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The above response is correct for the straight up conversion of the package to a WDP (scwdp.zip).

In case it helps, there are quite a few goodies that make use of the Azure Toolkit to generate WDPs and to then deploy to Azure in the [HabitatHome.Platform repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform/tree/develop/Azure)

The main PS scripts are in /Azure and a lot of it is called / used by build.cake. It's not for the faint of heart and needs some work but as I say it would contain some nuggets that you could probably make use of / learn from.