# Error when installing WDP in on-premises Sitecore 9.1 XP setup

Tags: azure, installation, paas, packages, web-deploy

I followed the steps described in this [SSE question/answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/how-to-convert-a-sitecore-package-into-a-wdp-package/18704#18704) to create my WDP.

Everything works like a charm when **deploying this WDP into a Sitecore Azure** Paas instance.

However, when I try to install it locally in my **on-premises Sitecore 9.1 XP** single instance, it doesn't work.

This is the command I'm using to install it locally:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="D:\coveoticore.scwdp.zip" -dest:auto -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -setParam:"Application Path"="coveoticore" -setParam:"Core Admin Connection String"="Data Source=.\HSANTOS2016;Initial Catalog=coveoticore_Core;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword" -setParam:"Master Admin Connection String"="Data Source=.\HSANTOS2016;Initial Catalog=coveoticore_Master;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword" -verbose
```

Those are the error messages I get:

```
Error: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'coveoticore_Core'. Try again later.
Error: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = NONE
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END


Error: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Error: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = NONE
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END
```

And this one:

```
Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
More Information: Could not deploy package.
Warning SQL72023: The database containment option has been changed to None.  This may result in deployment failure if the state of the database is not compliant with this containment level.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'coveoticore_Core'. Try again later.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = NONE
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END


Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = NONE
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END
```

Comment: With SIF 2.2.0 you can use the SkipDatabaseInstallation parameter to avoid DB installation and just deploy the website within the InstallWDP step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

So basically if your Sitecore package **contains database users** that must be deployed and the **target database already contains any user** (which is true for SC9.1 OOTB), you **can't create the WDP in the same way** you did for Azure.

From the [official documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/22/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/web-deploy-packages-for-a-module.html#UUID-0bedc2bc-86ad-640c-1f54-b8663a00c9d6_section-idm45247615367056):

> Use **DisableDacPacOptions** to create tables or users when you are
>   deploying. You must disable SqlDatabaseOptions for the module WDP
>   package if you want to deploy them to an on-premise instance. If you
>   do not disable SqlDatabaseOptions, msDeploy will try to convert the
>   contained database into an uncontained database and the attempts to
>   apply these options while deploying the module package produces the
>   wrong result.

## The Fix

Just add the **DisableDacPacOptions** option when calling the function to create your WDP `ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage`. The command-line should look like this:

```
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path "yourPackagePath.zip" -Destination "wdpOutputDirectoryPath" -force -verbose -DisableDacPacOptions "*"
```

Installing this new WDP should not produce any error message.